# Android Studio Java: How can I update my quantity if the product already exist's in my Cart Activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing an issue which is, I did not know how to update the product quantity where the product already exist in my cart activity. I am trying to retrieve my data from firebase, but not able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
private void addToCart() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Type").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    databaseReference
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(productID).exists()){
                                //update to firebase
                                String addedQty1 = "" + snapshot.child("addedQuantity").getValue();
                                int getQty = Integer.parseInt(addedQty1);
                                int currentQty = Integer.parseInt(addedQty);

                                int newAddedQty = getQty + currentQty;

                                String addedNewQty = String.valueOf(newAddedQty);

                                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap1.put("addedQuantity", "" + addedNewQty);

                                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Type");
                                databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(productID).updateChildren(hashMap1)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                //updated
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(ViewProductDetails.this, "Added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                //failed to update
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(ViewProductDetails.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            } else {
                                //Add to firebase
                                final String timestamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

                                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("cartID", "" + timestamp);
                                hashMap.put("accountID", "" + accountID);
                                hashMap.put("productID", "" + productID);
                                hashMap.put("orderFrom", "" + shopName);
                                hashMap.put("discountNote", "" + discountNote);
                                hashMap.put("originalPrice", "" + oriPrice);
                                hashMap.put("discountPrice", "" + discountedPrice);
                                hashMap.put("price", "" + price);
                                hashMap.put("productTitle", "" + productTitle);
                                hashMap.put("productCategory", "" + category);
                                hashMap.put("productSize", "" + size);
                                hashMap.put("productQuantity", "" + availableQty);
                                hashMap.put("addedQuantity", "" + addedQty);

                                //add to firebase
                                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Type");
                                databaseReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(productID).setValue(hashMap)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                              
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(ViewProductDetails.this, "Added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                //failed to update
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(ViewProductDetails.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

}
```

I have shared the code snippet where "else" statement works fine whereas "if" statement is failed to run. Hope anyone can help me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: What is the error you are getting and can you please share your database schema so I can share a solution according to your database.

Comment: From my code is, I’m unable to update my product quantity. I want my code to be run as if user press “add to cart” for the first time, the first quantity will be saved and displayed in the cart activity. 
When second time, user clicks on the same product, supposedly the quantity should be the first added quantity + second added quantity. But I cannot do this. It just replaced my first added quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic solution should look like this pseudocode:

```
if (product already in cart) {
  get current product count from cart
  increment product count
  store new count back in cart
}
```

That is one test and three actions.  Check that all four are present and that all four work.  If you can, it is better to test them separately so you can isolate errors more easily.

Comment: Hi, I have done this, yet it still cannot. The number is keeping increasing non-stop. And I cannot add new items now.